# About the definition of solutions of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the problem:  $y' = xy(y+2) $
If we consider the point $I(x,y)$ satisfying $y(y + 2) \neq 0$, we have a normal solution. 
 But in the opposite case, why do we deduce it only has solutions $y = 0$ and $y = -2$. 
If according to my understanding, by Wiki : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Existence_and_uniqueness_of_solutions 
, then why can we only determine the constant solution now?

Comment: If $y=0$, then it does not make sense when you divide $y(y+2)$ on both side.

Comment: @Mark what do you call a normal solution ?

Comment: I mean finding the solution in the usual way because then we only need to consider in $[x - a, x + a]$

Comment: If you solve your equation on a given interval $J$, there are two cases.
Either $y$ vanishes at a given point $t_0$ and $y$ must be constant to zero according to Picard-Lindelöf (unicity of the solution), or y doesn't vanish and you can apply the usual method. If you're looking for nonzero constant solutions $K$ then for $x \neq 0$ you have $K(K+2)=0$, so$ K=-2$

Comment: No, I mean how can we prove that it only has singular solutions like that, or that it has other singular solutions?

Comment: These solutions are not singular, they are just a special case of the solution method.

Comment: Why they are not singular? In my perspective, they are singular because it is satisfied in the neighbor of 0 or 2. Two functions y = 0 and y = -2 found so with x = 2, so the differential equation fails to have unique solution in the neighbor of 0 or 2.

Comment: In our program, we do not learn deeply about Mathematics. Is it necessary to understand the above problem?